# Pass data through an anonymous pipe to another program

Tags: c, linux, pipe

This is my code I'm trying to use to pass data to the other program.:

```
static int callWithFile(char* buff) {

    int myPipes[2];


    if( pipe( myPipes ) < 0 ){
        perror("Can't pipe through \n");
        exit(13);
    }

    int pid = fork();
    switch(pid){
        case 0:
            {
                if(verbose_flag) printf("pid is %d; pipe fds are.... %d & %d\n", getpid(), myPipes[PIPE_READ], myPipes[PIPE_WRITE]);

                //close (myPipes[PIPE_READ]);
                write (myPipes[PIPE_WRITE], buff, strlen(buff) + 1); 
                close (myPipes[PIPE_WRITE]);

                char* pipeArg;
                if(verbose_flag){
                    asprintf (&pipeArg, "/proc/%d/fd/%d", getpid(), myPipes[PIPE_READ]);
                    printf("\n%s\n", pipeArg);
                } 

                asprintf (&pipeArg, "/dev/fd/%d", myPipes[PIPE_READ]);


                char* progArgv[] = {
                    "prog",
                    "--new_settings",
                    pipeArg,
                    //"/dev/fd/0",
                    NULL
                };


                // This works just fine

                // FILE* fp = fopen(pipeArg, "r");
                // if (fp == NULL) {
                //     perror("Can't open fd pipe file \n");
                //     exit(14);
                // }

                // fread(buff, sizeof(char), strlen(buff) + 1, fp);

                // printf("buff: %s", buff);


                execvp(prog_path, progArgv);
                perror("execvp screwed up");
                exit(15);
            }

        case -1:
            perror("fork screwed up ");
            exit(16);
    }
    
    close (myPipes[PIPE_READ]);
    close (myPipes[PIPE_WRITE]);
    wait(NULL);

    puts("done");
}
```

In all aspects, the code appears to be correct and providing the file descriptor for the other program to read from.
However, for some reason, the other program tells it can't open and read the file.

This is the program that reads the data: https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-control-center/blob/master/src/common/classes/ConfigHandler.ts#L87
It complains: `Error on read option --new_settings with path: /dev/fd/4`

I already confirmed that it is correct JSON, so that shouldn't be the problem.

As for debugging it, I can't make it run on my machine for some reason.
`Cannot launch program because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.`.

My objective is to have the equivalent of this in bash:
`program <(echo $buff)`
Where `$buff` is the contents of the `buff` function argument.

Comment: Well, at first read, it appears the problem is described in the 2nd to last paragraph.

Comment: @ryyker My understanding of that paragraph is that it's meant to be uploaded to some sort of online judge/grader, and that problem only exists on OP's local machine.

Comment: @brunoais You need to post a minimal, reproducible example. Your example is not reproducible.

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but you're piping the data in a strange way.  Normally the parent would do the writing and the child would do the reading.  Here the child is both writing and reading, which may conceivably work in this specific case but would be problematic in general.  And the parent does nothing with the pipe at all, so why did you bother to create it before forking?

Comment: For debugging, can you replace `prog` with `cat`?

Comment: @NateEldredge cat prints correctly.  I also tried once again running in bash using `<(cat file_with_contents.json)` instead of my C program and that one works too.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your code is correct except this:

```
write (myPipes[PIPE_WRITE], buff, strlen(buff) + 1);
```

See that `+ 1`? That's the failure. You are sending a null byte (AKA character 0 or '\0') to the program when its JSON parser doesn't expect it.

Try this instead (without the `+ 1`):

```
write (myPipes[PIPE_WRITE], buff, strlen(buff));
```

Comment: ... and this is what solved it. It was a json parser issue after all. It's just that other programs deal with the null byte just fine and present strings with null byte as if they were nothing but this program just fails with a generic error.